# Getting error when inserting / updating to embeddable table from primary table having secondary tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a primary table with 2 secondary tables. Main table is called pushcode and it uses 2 secondary tables: sms_gateway_parameters and last_run_date. Now I am able to fetch data from database but my question is how do I insert into the embedded table?

I know embedded tables are treated as non entity class but isn't it possible to insert / update to the table from primary table if it is included as a secondary table?

Do I have to create a separate entity altogether if I want to insert/update the sms_gateway_parameters  table?

Currently I am getting the below error on running the application:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Embeddable class
> 'java.lang.Integer' may not have a property annotated '@Id' since it
> is used by
> 'com.dcb.smsbatch.dataLayer.entities.SMSCompleteData.smsgatewayParams.pushCode'
> as an '@EmbeddedId'

**SmsCompleteData.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pushcode")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@SecondaryTables({
      @SecondaryTable(name="sms_gateway_parameters", pkJoinColumns={
          @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="push_cd", referencedColumnName="push_cd"),
      }),  
      @SecondaryTable(name="last_run_date", pkJoinColumns={
          @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="push_cd", referencedColumnName="push_cd"),
      })
    })
public class SMSCompleteData {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "push_cd", table = "pushcode")
    Integer pushCode;
    
    @Column(name="is_multilingual")
    String multilingual;
    
    @Column(name="is_active")
    String status;
    
    @Column(name="sql_str")
    String finacleQuery;
    
    @Column(name="msg_template")
    String messageTemplate;
    
    @Column(name="msg_template_alternate")
    String AltMessageTemplate;
    
    @Column(name="fin_variables")
    String finVariables;
    
    @NotNull()
    String cron;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    String description;
    
     @Transient
     List<SchemeCode>  schemeCodes;
     
     @Transient
     @Column(name="MSG_SENT_COUNT", table="last_run_date")
     Integer totalCount;
     
     @Transient
     @Column(name="LST_POLL_TIME", table="last_run_date")
     String lastRunDate;
     
     @Embedded
     SmsGateway smsgatewayParams;
    
}
```

**SmsGateway.java**

```
@Data
@ToString
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SmsGateway {
    
    @EmbeddedId 
    @Column(name="push_cd")
    Integer pushCode;
    
    Integer ctype;
    String dcode;
    String subuid;
    String pwd;
}
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Embeddable classes are used to represent the state of an entity but don’t have a persistent identity of their own, unlike entity classes. Instances of an embeddable class share the identity of the entity that owns it. Embeddable classes exist only as the state of another entity.

If you want SmsGateway to be treated as the separate entity, you should not mark it as Embeddable.

Comment: Okay, i had made smsgateway an embedded class because it needs to be updated only when pushcode table gets updated but since smsgateway kind of represents a separate entity in reality so it shouldn't exactly be integrated within pushcode. But just for clarification, isn't it possible to update secondary table when the primary table is updated? Or are secondary tables, read only tables?

Comment: I think you can already achive this using @SecondaryTables annotaion. When you insert any data to the pushcode table, hibernate should automatically insert a row to the smsgateway as well. For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730047/jpa-hibernate-mapping-with-secondarytable-annotation

Comment: I initially had created a smsgateway object with valid values and when I tried to run the save() of smsCompleteDataRepository, i was getting a hibernate error that said subuid wasn't found in pushcode table. Subuid is part of the secondary table sms_gateway_parameters.

Comment: The sms_gateway_parameters table already has a foreign key mapping where it's push_cd is mapped to push_cd of pushcode table

Comment: It wont be able to map the subuid column from primary table to secondary table as you have not added this to the SMSCompleteData table. I think thats why it is getting error. Your secondary table is getting the data from the primary table.

Comment: I thought providing the smsgateway object with valid values to the smscompletedata table would internally add the data to the secondary table. I think in my case, i would have to remove the embedded annotation and make smsgateway a separate entity altogether. Thank you for your help @rahulP